# How to configure custom UITableViewCell just once?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, configuration

Consider we have

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: HomeViewController.episodeTableViewCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! EpisodeTableViewCell

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.titleLabel.text = episodesArray[indexPath.row].title

        return cell
}
```

What if I want to separate cell configuration part (setting backgroundColor and cell selectionStyle) which gonna be same for all of the cells to prevent those lines of code execute each time tableView: cellForRowAt: is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to place cell configuration code in `awakeFromNib()` inside Cell, in this way it will be called just once.

Like this

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    setupCell()
}

private func setupCell() {
    selectionStyle = .none
    backgroundColor = .red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function inside your cell class.

```
configure() {
   // setup cell properties here
}
```

Then you only need to write cell.configure() in place of all your setup lines.

If you want it to be even more generic, you can put this configure function in an extension

```
extension UITableViewCell {
   func configure() {
     // configure code lines
   }
 }
```

Comment: What you say is just to wrap configuration code into a method inside Cell class and call it from `tableView: cellForRowAt indexPath:`, so that's not solve what I asked - configuration of the cell will be called despite cell is initiated and is going to be reused. But thanks, you pointed me proper direction